# On using a batch file in cmd Could not find or load main class for a program

Tags: java, class, exception, cmd

[The error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkTwN.png)

Error: Could not find or load main class JDBCExample1.java

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:JDBCExample1.java

```
Batch file used:
set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin;
set classpath=C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar;.
javac JDBCExample1.java
java JDBCExample1.java
pause
```

The PATH and the CLASSPATH have been set correctly in Environment variables too.

Also the directory used is correct.

Comment: I have saved the program JDBCExample1.java in the folder named JDBCODBCprograms which is saved on  my Desktop.                                      
 So I am using  :    cd  C:\Users\Siddhi\Desktop\JDBCODBCprograms               to set the directory

Comment: the porblem is bei running java compiler javac you gnerate a new file. This new file can be run using javac not the source code file

Comment: In general replacing __local__ `PATH` by a user defined `PATH` not containing anymore Windows system directory path is no good idea on using a batch file as it can be read on answer on  [What is the reason for '...' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564) I suggest to use in your batch file `set "PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.2\bin;%PATH%"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving 
“java JDBCExample1”
Instead of 
“java JDBCExample1.java”
In the last line. One does not use .java while running the program